# how to place and wrap a legend in ggplot

Tags: r

I want to place and wrap the legend to the right bottom of the plot like the original heatmap (I circled this portion in red).

the data are in this [link](https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv):
[image]

Little background about this data, it seems the heatmap is based on the z-score of the mean of the 4 groups, since they have two groups, I figured may be the team generated a mean of each two columns and derived z-score from the mean for these four groups.
I tried this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(matrixStats)
library(pheatmap)
library(heatmaps)

dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

head(dfc)

dfg <- dfc %>% dplyr::filter(tracking_id %in% c(
    "Ifng", "Igfbp7", "Il13", "Il4", "Itgb1", "Rbpj",
    "Tnfsf11", "Xcl1", "Ern1", "Furin", "Il5", "Nrp1", "Ptprs",
    "Spry1", "Vdr", "Foxp3", "Prdm1", "Itgb8", "Lamc1", "Ptpn5",
    "Bmpr2", "Csf1", "Dst", "Myo1e", "Pmaip1", "Itgav", "Ramp1",
    "Sdc4", "Areg", "Calca", "Capg", "Ccr2", "Cd44", "Il10", "Il1rl1",
    "Maf", "Rora", "S100a4", "Adam8", "Adam19", "Anxa2", "Bcl2l1",
    "Csda", "Ehd1", "Hist1h1b", "Id2", "Il2ra", "Il2rb", "Lgals1",
    "Lmna", "Mki67", "Penk", "Podnl1", "S100a6", "Vim")) 

dfg$CD44low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
head(dfg)
dim(dfg)
head(dfg)
rownameshm <-paste(dfg[,1])
rownameshm
colnameshm <- paste(dQuote(colnames(dfg[0, 10:13])), collapse = ", ")
colnameshm
dfg$Mean <- rowMeans(dfg[,10:13])
dfg$sd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dfg[,10:13]))
head(dfg)

zScore <- function(p){
for(n in 10:13){
    p[[n]]=(as.numeric(p[[n]])-as.numeric(p[[14]]))/as.numeric(p[[15]])
    }
return(p)
}

Matrix_zScore <- t(apply(dfg,1,zScore))
head(Matrix_zScore)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- mapply(Matrix_zScore[,10:13], FUN=as.numeric)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- matrix(data=Matrix_zScore_temp, ncol=4, nrow=55)
Matrix_zScore_temp1<-as.data.frame(Matrix_zScore_temp)

rownames(Matrix_zScore_temp) <- dfg$tracking_id
plot_frame <- reshape2::melt(Matrix_zScore_temp)

library("tidyverse")
library(repr)
options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=8)


ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +
  theme_minimal() +  theme(
           legend.position = c(1, 0), 
      legend.justification = c(-0.9, 0),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
   legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(0.3,"cm"))
```

My heatmap looks like this:

[image]

I tried the following without luck:

1.

```
zmap001 <- ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +
  theme_minimal() +
theme(
           legend.position = c(1, 0), 
      legend.justification = c(0.9, 0),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
   legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(0.3,"cm")) 

zmap002 <- zmap001 + guides(title = "Relative gene expression\n        (z score)", subtitle = "(z score)")
zmap002
```

2. 

```
zmap01 <- ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +
  theme_minimal() +
theme( legend.position = c(1, 0), 
      legend.justification = c(0.9, 0),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
   legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(0.3,"cm"), legend.title = element_text(angle = -90)) 

zmap02 <- zmap01 + guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "right", title = "Relative gene expression\n        (z score)", subtitle = "(z score)"))
zmap02
```

3. 

```
zmap01 <- ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value), colour=str_wrap()) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29")) +
  theme_minimal() +
theme( plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"), complete = TRUE, 
           legend.position = c(1, 0), 
      legend.justification = c(0.9, 0),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
   legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(0.3,"cm"), legend.title = element_text(angle = -90)) 

zmap02 <- zmap01 + guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "right", title = "Relative gene expression\n(z score)"))
zmap02
```

How to remove these little lines:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some data where every value falls between -1 and 1. Then, you can get [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y9zH.png) using this:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
    geom_tile(color = "white", show.legend = TRUE) +
    scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
    labs(y = "", fill = "") +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        colours = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29"),
        breaks = c(1, 0, -1),
        labels = c(1, 0, -1),
        limits = c(-1, 1),
        guide = "colorbar"
    ) +
    guides(
        fill = guide_colourbar(
            title = "Relative gene expression \n (z score)",
            title.position = "right",
            title.theme = element_text(angle = -90, size = 7),
            direction = "vertical",
            ticks = TRUE
        )
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        plot.margin = margin(r = unit(50, "cm")),
        legend.position = c(1.11, 0.1025),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.3,"cm"),
        legend.title.align = 0.5
    )
```

You can use `plot.margin` to adjust the margins of the plot and create more space for the legend. In this case, we can add space to the right side of the plot using `margin(r = unit(50, "cm"))`. Using this with `legend.position` will let you position the legend exactly where you want it.

It's not exact, as it seems the `title.hjust` argument for `guide_colourbar()` only adjusts the last line of the title, but you can get around this slightly by decreasing the size of the title. However, this might guide you closer to what you're after.

[Here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_colourbar.html) is the `guide_colourbar()` documentation, which might help for the title.

Comment: This so so helpful @ JustinSingh ! I appreciate the help. I just tried and played with some numbers there and I got almost what I want, but the color came off different, any input on how to reproduce the color? Also how to remove these little lines (I updated the question with your image)

Comment: For the tick marks, you can use one of the following: `axis.text.x = element_blank()`,
  `axis.text.y = element_blank()`, and/or `axis.ticks = element_blank()` within your `theme()`. As for the colors, that might be due to the `scale_fill_gradientn()` options: `breaks`, `labels`, and `limits` -- `breaks` and `labels` work together in this case to specify what values should be labels on the legend; whereas, `limits` limits the data and removes anything outside of its range. In my case, I created data that was within the range of -1 to 1, but never each value. You can try removing `limits`.

Comment: Thank you so much again! I tried the `axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()` it removes the texts but not the tick lines! @JustinSingh

Comment: I deleted my other comment, since those lines you noted are not actually tick marks. I didn't notice originally, but it's actually the grid in the background *behind* the heatmap. To remove this, we add `panel.grid.major = element_blank()` to the `theme()`. (As for my deleted comment, `axis.ticks.y` and `axis.ticks.x` are the actual options for tick marks, not `axis.text.*` I mistyped)

Comment: It worked fine, but it shows a gap between the figure and text! can I make the text closer to the plot or control how close? @JustinSingh

Comment: You can adjust the *axis tick labels* by setting the margin of them, similarly to `plot.margin`. The `theme()` option will look similarly to this: `axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = unit(-3, "cm")))`. Here, I set the margin on the *left* side to a negative number to remove part of the margin on the left of the right-side y-axis tick labels, so that they move closer to the plot. Hope that helps! And, to avoid extended discussion, we can move to chat if you need further help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224545/discussion-between-user432797-and-justin-singh).